# How can be used the "^" character at the end of an installation package on apt

Tags: apt, package-management, system-installation

I have an special question about APT command-line tool.
When I use `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop^` does different things than `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop`. I don't know why this happened, and why it do not work with all packages like if you do it with gparted like: `sudo apt install gparted^` it does nothing. So I want to know how the final `^` works on apt and why it works just in special cases.